# Regex in @CrossOrigin SpringBoot

Tags: regex, spring-boot, spring-security, cors, cross-domain

I am trying to define `origins` which are to be allowed to execute a REST Service. I am working on Java(1.8), SpringBoot (1.5.9). I have tried to implement CORS in 2 ways:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:8080")
@RequestMapping(value="/questions")
public String readCSV() throws IOException, URISyntaxException  {
    /** Some Logic **/
    return str;
}
```

OR

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {    
    String origins = "http://localhost:8080";       
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST")
                .allowedOrigins(origins)
                .maxAge(3600);
        super.addCorsMappings(registry);
    }
}
```

Both the above cases works. But I want to change that `http://localhost:8080` to some meaningful regex, which will match to some particular domain name, but the subdoamin name and the port number may vary.
For example, let's say the *desired domain name* is **innovation.com** and few *accepted urls* would be **we.innovation.com:8081**, **my.innovation.com:8090** etc.
The problem is, whenever I put some regex instead of the static URLs, it throws CORS error and is not allowed to access the service. Even in the case when I used regex which allows any valid url, it blocks `localhost:8080`.
I have tried regex like:
`^((?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)\\.)+innovation.com(:\d{2,4})`
`^https?://(?:[^./@]+\.)*domain\.com(?![^/])`
`^(http[s]:\/\/)?([A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}\\.)+innovation.com(:\d{2,4})`

Comment: Why do you think that this is possible? Do you have any link showing that this is possible?

Comment: Thanks @dur for your quick reply. Exactly my question. Is this even _possible_?

Comment: There seems to be no build-in way to do that, which drives me crazy, too. As a workaround for a known number of combinations, "origins" can be a comma separated list of values, like "http://example.com:8080, https://secure.example.com:8081".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable wildcard in CORS spring security + webFlux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53412178/enable-wildcard-in-cors-spring-security-webflux)

Comment: This is possible using `config.setAllowedPatterns(List.of("http://*.localhost:4200"));` See the diff it's `setAllowedPatterns` not `setAllowedOrigins`

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be extending the spring cors configuration, there is a method called checkOrigin, which could be rewritten to handle regular expressions: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.java#L425-L455

Luckily someone did that already: https://github.com/looorent/spring-security-jwt/blob/master/src/main/java/be/looorent/security/jwt/RegexCorsConfiguration.java

Answer (score 2):

As of Spring Boot 2.4.x or Spring 5.3, CorsRegistration can add origin as a pattern. See [CorsRegistration#allowedOriginPatterns](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/CorsRegistration.html#allowedOriginPatterns-java.lang.String...-)

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using `config.setAllowedPatterns(List.of("http://*.localhost:4200"));` See the diff it's `setAllowedPatterns` not `setAllowedOrigins`

Sample code:

```html
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://yourowndomain.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList("https://*.otherdomain.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(
                Arrays.asList(HttpMethod.GET.toString(), HttpMethod.POST.toString(), HttpMethod.DELETE.toString()));
        configuration.setMaxAge(Duration.ofMillis(3600));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(
                Arrays.asList(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, HttpHeaders.ACCEPT));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```